# Prosecuting prison escapees

Tags: criminal-law, california

Would the actual escape from a **state** prison ever incur federal investigation, federal charges, and/or federal prosecution?  If not, who investigates, charges, and prosecutes escapees for escaping from state prisons in California, USA?

Answer (score 2):

If you escape from state prison and flee to another state, that fleeing is a federal crime. Escape from federal prison is a [federal crime](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/751) (thus pursued by the federal government). Otherwise, escape from (California) prison is a [California crime](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/penal-code/pen-sect-4532.html), pursued by California. The federal law regarding escape is stated in terms of who has custody, not the jurisdiction whose laws you violated. So a person convicted of a state-level crime and incarcerated in federal prison (for security reasons) would be subject to federal investigation and prosecution. The situation where a federal convict is housed in a state prison doesn't appear to arise. So it would appear that if you break the law in California, are imprisoned in state prison, and escape but stay in the state, it is only California that will investigate and prosecute.

Comment: "The situation where a federal convict is housed in a state prison doesn't appear to arise." FWIW, federal criminal defendants are routinely confined in state and local jails while awaiting trial and when sentenced for misdemeanors pursuant to contractual arrangements between the Justice Department of the U.S. government and the government that runs the jail. I don't know if escape in that case would be a federal crime, a state crime, or both.